# Commands Executable & Console Logging before all Shards Spawned

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm on Discord.js v13 and using its shard manager, but two dilemmas here.

1. My users try to do commands immediately after a routine restart and Discord returns "the application did not respond."
2. I want to log in my console when all shards are ready and the bot is up, even if I hard code a number of `if 2 shards are spawned then console log ready`.

I believe both issues can be solved with an event to tell me when all shards are ready. Is there one in Discord.js/the Discord API?

My initial approach was the client.on('ready', async () => {}); but that seems to run every shard spawn.

Answer (score 0):

You Can do this before manager.spawn()

Believing your shard file to be same as the one specified [here](https://discordjs.guide/sharding/#sharding-file)

You can log that sharding process is going to spawn, etc.